# How to remove Event Listener in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, scroll, event-listener

I'm trying to implement lazy scrolling in my script and it's working well up until it reaches the end and I want to stop it from making extra requests.

I've added an event listener to my code using:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", _.throttle(checkScroll, 500));
```

However, when I try to remove it, it still seems to keep listening and acting on the event.

I've tried:

```
if (json.articles.length == 0) {
                $(".articles").append("<br>That's all folks!");
                window.removeEventListener("scroll", _.throttle(checkScroll, 500));
}
```

and

```
if (json.articles.length == 0) {
                $(".articles").append("<br>That's all folks!");
                window.off("scroll");
}
```

but neither seem to be working.

Comment: you should cache the `_.throttle(checkScroll, 500)` instance, I don't think it return the same instance every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the event listener using plain Javascript, the only way to remove it would be to save a reference to the result of calling `_.throttle` that you pass to `addEventListener`:

```
const handler = _.throttle(checkScroll, 500);
window.addEventListener("scroll", handler);
// ...
window.removeEventListener("scroll", handler);
```

You could only do something like `window.off('scroll')` if you also add the handler using jQuery (eg `$(window).on(...)` and then `$(window).off(...)`). If you add the handler with Javascript, jQuery's `off` won't be usable.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the event handler in jQuery using `on` and remove it using `off`. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mri_dula/g1e7pjon/6/) to illustrate it.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(ev) { //add handler
    ...
})

$(window).off('scroll', function(ev) { //remove handler
    ...
})
```